# Heroku release phase commands are not executed

Tags: python, django, docker, heroku

I try to deploy a django application on heroku using a build manifest. The application seems to be deployed correctly, but the commands in the release phase do not seem to be executed.

This is my heroku.yml:

```yaml
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - python manage.py migrate
    - python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
run:
  web: gunicorn hello_django.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy source code to container
COPY ./src .

# create directory for statics
RUN mkdir staticfiles
```

The commands specified in the release phase are not executed. I know that, because the database is not being migrated and the staticfiles directory is empty. I also know that the rest of my application is actually configured correctly, because when I include this line in my Dockerfile at the end:

```
RUN python manage.py collectstatic
```

then the statics are collected and the application is running.

I also installed the plugin `heroku-manifest` with this command:
`heroku plugins:install @heroku-cli/plugin-manifest` and set the stack of my app to container with `heroku stack:set container -a <app name>`

What am I missing?

#### Update

actually it seems the `migrate` command is executed, but not `collectstatic`. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and came up with a partial solution. I was able to get the `collectstatic` command to run by using the `&&` command. Here's what your `heroku.yml` file would look like.

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
release:
  image: web
  command:
    - python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
run:
  web: gunicorn hello_django.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

My guess is that only one command is allowed but it's just a guess. I checked the documentation for `release` on heroku but it didn't say anything like that. Although, in their example only one command was used.

Anyway, using `&&` worked for me and I can see from the release logs that the `collectstatic` command was executed.

**However:**
Even though the `collectstatic` command was executed, my newest release did not include any of the style changes I had made. So I still ended up having to run `collectstatic` before pushing the code to Heroku. I still don't have a solution for how add the collect static step into an automated workflow.

**Update:** After digging around some more I think the best option for me is to add `collectstatic` to github actions. As mentioned in the comment by Eduardo it seems that the release phase of Heroku does not persist the collected files data...

Comment: It seems release phase does not persist the collected files data.

Comment: @EduardoGomes Yeah I think you're right. Anyway I'll update my answer but I think a good option for automating the collectstatic process is to add it to github actions.

Comment: I got it working by collecting static files in the end of the container build. But to do that I had to fake some environment variables so that `manage.py` wouldn't complain about my settings.

Comment: You should collect static in your dockerfile!?